# Parallelize bash script in HPC slurm

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, hpc, slurm

I have a file like this:

```
bash scripts/1-Call_HC.sh Uni_Mont_1_3 /home/db/fagiolo/config_fagiolo_Pvulgaris.sh > logs/HC_Uni_Mont_1_3.e 2> logs/HC_Uni_Mont_1_3.o
bash scripts/1-Call_HC.sh Uni_Mont_27_1 /home/db/fagiolo/config_fagiolo_Pvulgaris.sh > logs/HC_Uni_Mont_27_1.e 2> logs/HC_Uni_Mont_27_1.o
bash scripts/1-Call_HC.sh Uni_Mont_27_2 /home/db/fagiolo/config_fagiolo_Pvulgaris.sh > logs/HC_Uni_Mont_27_2.e 2> logs/HC_Uni_Mont_27_2.o
bash scripts/1-Call_HC.sh Uni_Mont_29_1 /home/db/fagiolo/config_fagiolo_Pvulgaris.sh > logs/HC_Uni_Mont_29_1.e 2> logs/HC_Uni_Mont_29_1.o
bash scripts/1-Call_HC.sh Uni_Mont_29_3 /home/db/fagiolo/config_fagiolo_Pvulgaris.sh > logs/HC_Uni_Mont_29_3.e 2> logs/HC_Uni_Mont_29_3.o
bash scripts/1-Call_HC.sh Uni_Mont_30_1 /home/db/fagiolo/config_fagiolo_Pvulgaris.sh > logs/HC_Uni_Mont_30_1.e 2> logs/HC_Uni_Mont_30_1.o
bash scripts/1-Call_HC.sh Uni_Mont_30_2 /home/db/fagiolo/config_fagiolo_Pvulgaris.sh > logs/HC_Uni_Mont_30_2.e 2> logs/HC_Uni_Mont_30_2.o
```

In a normal machine I will use `nohup parallel -j 3 < file.sh` to parallelize the execution. I would like to do the same on a HPC server with Slurm using the queue of the server.
How can I do that?
Thanks a lot,
Denise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [job array](https://slurm.schedmd.com/job_array.html) should do the job here.

Write a submission script like this:

```
#! /bin/bash
#SBATCH --ntask=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=...
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=...
#SBATCH --array=0-6

OPTIONS=(1_3 27_1 27_2 29_1 29_3 30_1 30_2)
CURROPT=${OPTIONS[$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID]}

bash scripts/1-Call_HC.sh Uni_Mont_$CURROPT /home/db/fagiolo/config_fagiolo_Pvulgaris.sh > logs/HC_Uni_Mont_$CURROPT.e 2> logs/HC_Uni_Mont_$CURROPT.o
```

and submit it with `sbatch`. This will create 6 independent jobs that will be scheduled in parallel.

Comment: I'm doing it but is always the same sample starting

Comment: I've change CURROPT=${OPTIONS[$SLURM_ARRAY_JOBID]} with CURROPT=${OPTIONS[$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID]} and it works! Thanks

Comment: @DeniseLavezzari Indeed, thanks, corrected.